# How to get rid of unresolved external errors while trying to decode audio using ffmpeg

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I am trying to decode a audio file using ffmpeg, while I am doing this I am getting many unresolved external errors. I am new to ffmpeg libraries, any suggestion for the problem would be a great help.

Thank you.

```
        void audioDecode(char* filename)
{
    FILE *file;
    AVFormatContext *audioInputFormatContext;
    AVInputFormat *audioInputFormat = NULL;
    AVCodec *audioCodec;
    AVCodecContext *audioCodecContext;

    av_register_all();

    char *audioInputDeviceName = filename;
    int ret;
    int audioIndex = 0;
    AVPacket pkt;
    av_init_packet(&pkt);

    avformat_network_init();

    audioInputFormatContext = avformat_alloc_context();
    ret = avformat_open_input(&audioInputFormatContext, audioInputDeviceName, audioInputFormat, NULL);

    if (ret == 0)
    {
        ret = avformat_find_stream_info(audioInputFormatContext, 0);
        if (ret >= 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < audioInputFormatContext->nb_streams; i++) {
                if (audioInputFormatContext->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
                    audioIndex = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            audioCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(audioInputFormatContext->streams[audioIndex]->codecpar->codec_id);
            audioCodecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(audioCodec);
            avcodec_parameters_to_context(audioCodecContext, audioInputFormatContext->streams[audioIndex]->codecpar);

            if (avcodec_open2(audioCodecContext, audioCodec, NULL) >= 0)
            {
                ret = av_read_frame(audioInputFormatContext, &pkt);
                AVPacket encodePacket;
                AVFrame* decodeFrame = av_frame_alloc();
                int dec_got_frame = 0;
                if (ret == 0)
                {
                    ret = avcodec_send_packet(audioCodecContext, &pkt);
                    if (ret < 0)
                        printf("Error");
                }
                ret = avcodec_receive_frame(audioCodecContext, decodeFrame);

                if (ret >= 0)
                    dec_got_frame = 1;
                if (dec_got_frame)
                {

                    fopen_s(&file, filename, "wb");
                    fwrite(pkt.data, 1, pkt.size, file);
                    fclose(file);

                }

                av_frame_free(&decodeFrame);

            }
        }
    }

    avformat_close_input(&audioInputFormatContext);
    avcodec_free_context(&audioCodecContext);

    av_packet_unref(&pkt);
}
```

Comment: Please provide some example of the errors you are getting.

Comment: Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _avcodec_alloc_context3 referenced in function "void __cdecl audioDecode(char *)" (?audioDecode@@YAXPAD@Z)

Comment: And you are linking to avcodec, avformat and avutil libraries, right? With correct names for your ffmpeg installation?

Comment: Yes, I am doing it properly as I did for my other ffmpeg projects. Then also I am getting this error.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got rid of those errors, but still I was not able to decode the audio file. The file which I want to decode is a mp2 file. Can you please tell me if anything is wrong with the code?

Comment: One obvious thing is that you receive encoded packets in `pkt` but then give empty `encodePacket` into codec. Second thing is that you write encoded packets into file instead of decoded.

Comment: Hi Mr.Andrey, This is my updated code. I still get the problem near fwrite, can you please tell me if I am making some mistake?

Comment: Assuming you want to write decoded audio: you still writing encoded packet. You need to write decoded data which `avcodec_receive_frame` placed into `decodeFrame`. Also you are reopening output file every time so each new frame gets written into same place in file. There are some smaller issues with the code but they probably don't matter for this particular case.

Comment: Thank you. My aim to decode mp2 file to pcm format and then I want to extend this to achieve transcoding along with the encoding. So now do I have to send my decodeFrame to fwrite() ??

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to assume that you've already connected to the stream source and have the codec context by what you've mentioned in the comments.

These are snippets from my own project decoding the audio frames.

Decode the audio packet:

```
void FFMPEG::process_audio_packet(AVPacket *pkt) {
    int got;
    avcodec_decode_audio4(aud_stream.context, aud_stream.frame, &got, pkt);
    if (got) Audio.add_av_frame(aud_stream.frame);
}
```

Process the completed frame and extract a stereo 16 bit signed buffer:

```
void AudioManager::add_av_frame(AVFrame *frame) {
    int     nsamples    = frame->nb_samples;
    int     sample_rate = frame->sample_rate;
    int     channels    = frame->channels;
    AVSampleFormat format = (AVSampleFormat) frame->format;
    bool    planar      = av_sample_fmt_is_planar(format) == 1;

    int64_t pts         = av_frame_get_best_effort_timestamp(frame);
    //double ftime;

    /*if (ffmpeg.vid_stream.stream_id != -1)
        ftime = av_q2d(ffmpeg.aud_stream.context->time_base) * pts;
    else
        ftime = av_q2d(ffmpeg.vid_stream.context->time_base) * pts;*/

    AudioBuffer *buffer = NULL;

    if (planar) {   // handle planar audio frames
        /*
         * PLANAR frames conversion
         * ------------------------
         */
        if (channels == 1) {      // MONO

            //LOGD("Processing PLANAR MONO");
            /*
             * MONO
             */

            if (format == AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16P) {     // 16 bit signed
                if ((buffer = alloc_buffer(frame))) {   // allocated okay?
                    short *channel = (short*)frame->data[0];
                    short *buff = buffer->data;
                    for (int c = 0; c < nsamples; c++) {
                        *buff++ = *channel;
                        *buff++ = *channel++;
                    }
                    queue_new_buffer(buffer);
                }
                return;
            }
            if (format == AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S32P) {     // 32 bit signed
                if ((buffer = alloc_buffer(frame))) {    // allocated okay?
                    int32_t *channel = (int32_t*)frame->data[0];
                    short *buff = buffer->data;
                    for (int c = 0; c < nsamples; c++) {
                        int16_t s = (int16_t) (*channel++ >> 16);
                        *buff++ = s;
                        *buff++ = s;
                    }
                    queue_new_buffer(buffer);
                }
                return;
            }
            if (format == AV_SAMPLE_FMT_U8P) {      // 8 bit unsigned
                if ((buffer = alloc_buffer(frame))) {    // allocated okay?
                    uint8_t *channel = (uint8_t*)frame->data[0];
                    short *buff = buffer->data;
                    for (int c = 0; c < nsamples; c++) {
                        int16_t s = ((int16_t)(*channel++ - 128) << 8);
                        *buff++ = s;
                        *buff++ = s;
                    }
                    queue_new_buffer(buffer);
                }
            }
            return; // scrap if no audio buffer (highly unlikely)

        } else if (channels == 2) {                         // STEREO

            //LOGD("Processing PLANAR STEREO");
            /*
             * STEREO
             */

            if (format == AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16P) {     // 16 bit signed
                if ((buffer = alloc_buffer(frame))) {    // allocated okay
                    short *channel1 = (short*)frame->data[0];
                    short *channel2 = (short*)frame->data[1];
                    short *buff = buffer->data;
                    for (int c = 0; c < nsamples; c++) {
                        *buff++ = *channel1++;
                        *buff++ = *channel2++;
                    }
                    queue_new_buffer(buffer);
                }
                return;
            }
            if (format == AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S32P) {     // 32 bit signed
                if ((buffer = alloc_buffer(frame))) {    // allocated okay?
                    int32_t *channel1 = (int32_t*)frame->data[0];
                    int32_t *channel2 = (int32_t*)frame->data[1];
                    short *buff = buffer->data;
                    for (int c = 0; c < nsamples; c++) {
                        int16_t s1 = (int16_t) (*channel1++ >> 16);
                        int16_t s2 = (int16_t) (*channel2++ >> 16);
                        *buff++ = s1;
                        *buff++ = s2;
                    }
                    queue_new_buffer(buffer);
                }
                return;
            }
            if (format == AV_SAMPLE_FMT_U8P) {      // 8 bit unsigned
                if ((buffer = alloc_buffer(frame))) {    // allocated okay?
                    uint8_t *channel1 = (uint8_t*)frame->data[0];
                    uint8_t *channel2 = (uint8_t*)frame->data[1];
                    short *buff = buffer->data;
                    for (int c = 0; c < nsamples; c++) {
                        int16_t s1 = ((int16_t)(*channel1++ - 128) << 8);
                        int16_t s2 = ((int16_t)(*channel2++ - 128) << 8);
                        *buff++ = s1;
                        *buff++ = s2;
                    }
                    queue_new_buffer(buffer);
                }
            }
            return;

        }   // TODO: Handle more channels at a later date

    } else {        // handle non-planar audio frames
        /*
         * INTERLEAVED conversion
         * ----------------------
         */
    }
}
```

Process the audio buffer:

```
void AudioManager::queue_new_buffer(AudioBuffer *buffer) {
    if (buffer) {   // valid buffer

        // apply volume gain (only working with stereo)

        if (volume != 100) {
            short *data = buffer->data;
            int num_samples = buffer->nsamples << 1;
            while (num_samples--) {
                long sample = ((long)*data * volume) / 100;
                if (sample < -32768) sample = -32768;
                if (sample >  32767) sample =  32767;
                *data++ = (short)sample;
            }
        }

        // add buffer to queue

        buffer->used = true;

        double pts_start = get_pts_start_time();

        decode_pos = (++decode_pos) % MAX_AUD_BUFFERS;
        if (decode_pos == playback_pos)
            playback_pos = (++playback_pos) % MAX_AUD_BUFFERS;

        if (ffmpeg.vid_stream.stream_id == -1 && pts_start < 0.0) {
            set_pts_start_time(buffer->frame_time);
            set_sys_start_time(Display.get_current_render_time());
            LOGD("START TIME FROM AUDIO STREAM...");
        }

        //LOGI("Audio buffer queued %d (%d)", decode_pos, playback_pos);
    }
}
```